# English words in Flag list from Profile page

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Desculpe, eu não sei como verificar se ele já está reportado, mas na minha lista de sinalizações das palavras inglesas "pediu" e "por" aparecem mostrando quando e quem fez a pergunta. Eles não deveriam estar em Português?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you're referring to. Does the screenshot I posted correspond to the same page where you noticed the bug?

Comment: Yes, except it was two questions I have managed to flag, so it is `asked` and `by`, but same problem. Thanks.

Comment: And +1+ for your profile description ;)